# How to install Mono v3+ in Ubuntu?

Tags: ubuntu, command-line, software-installation, make, mono

How can I install [the latest release of Mono](https://github.com/mono/mono/releases) in Ubuntu Saucy?

In order to develop in a free OS, I need to setup Mono (that now [supports .NET 4.5](http://mono-project.com/Compatibility)). This is what I did:

1. Download and uncompress `mono-mono-3.2.5`
2. Run `./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr/local` (finished ok)
3. Run `make`, but it exit with error checking dependencies:

terminal-output:

```
....
mkdir -p -- build/deps
make[6]: gmcs: Command not found
make[6]: *** [build/deps/basic-profile-check.exe] Error 127
*** The compiler 'gmcs' doesn't appear to be usable.
*** You need Mono version 2.4 or better installed to build MCS
*** Check mono README for information on how to bootstrap a Mono installation.
make[5]: *** [do-profile-check] Error 1
make[4]: *** [profile-do--basic--all] Error 2
make[3]: *** [profiles-do--all] Error 2
make[2]: *** [all-local] Error 2
make[2]: Leaving directory `/home/hogar/Software/mono-mono-3.2.5/runtime'
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/hogar/Software/mono-mono-3.2.5'
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

But to install `mono-gmcs`, Ubuntu will also install `mono-runtime` *v2.10.8.1-5ubuntu2*. And that is exactly what I'm trying to not install, an old version of *mono*.

This is confusing me, what should I do?

Comment: This might help: http://mono.1490590.n4.nabble.com/Building-source-fails-gmcs-command-not-found-td4659673.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needed to have another instance of `mono` already installed, so `apt-get install mono-gmcs` did the job. Then, a [new error](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6523212/) appeared, and the only [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13862635/1505348) seemed to be using the GitHub package:

```
git clone git://github.com/mono/mono.git
cd mono
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr/local
make
make install
```

Now [I have installed](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6523219/) the latest version of mono.

**NOTE:** now [I am not able to run](http://paste.ubuntu.com/6523221/) any mono program, e.g. *monodevelop*. I couldn't find the solution to the exception, so now I'm downgrading mono to an old & compatible version.

PS: If you find the solution, please leave a comment :)